How to Render Nested Array to Antd Design Table Datasource Component using React js
Hope you all doing fine. I am here for some advice from you guys.
I am having an nested array which I would like to render the rows at ant design table datasource object.
After tried many things I am here seeking help from the experts. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
My Array Structure from console log:
Array(1)
0: Array(2)
    0: 
        subTasks: []
        taskDate: "2024-05-28T06:11:21.012Z"
        taskNote: "hi"
        taskPriority: "normal"
        taskStage: "todo"
        taskTitle: "task 2"
        __v: 0
        _id: "6655759970234b4bdd056f46"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    1: 
        subTasks: []
        taskDate: "2024-05-26T08:08:33.333Z"
        taskNote: "hello"
        taskPriority: "high"
        taskStage: "todo"
        taskTitle: "task1"
        __v: 0
        _id: "6652ee194675a5e07bc2e5a4"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

My Ant Design Code:
tasks is the array object.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

export default function DataTable({ tasks }) {

<Table key={`${uniqueId()}`}
    columns={dataTableColumns}
    rowKey={(item) => item._id}
    **dataSource={datasource}**
    pagination={true} />
}

EDIT:
I want to render the tasks. I am getting all the data by using map but couldn't find a way to place it properly as a table.
{
 tasks.length > 0 && tasks[0].map((task, index) => ( <Table dataSource = ? /> )) 
}


You want to render all tasks as a nested data structure i.e. tree or just a flat list? If flat just pass dataSource like this dataSource={tasks.flat()}

I want to render the tasks. I am getting all the data by using map but couldn't find a way to place it properly as a table.
{tasks.length > 0 && tasks[0].map((task, index) => (    ))
}
